# Proving that network weight is equal to weight in linearly ordered spaces.

Tags: general-topology, cardinals, network

I'm trying to prove one final result for my thesis on cardinal functions on hyperspaces, which states that for a LOTS (linearly ordered topological space) $X$, we have that $nw(X) = w(X)$.

I have already proven this for compact spaces, locally compact spaces and metrizable spaces, but after a long time have failed to conjure a proof for this one. Interestingly, this result is often cited to Engelking's General Topology, 3.12.4(d), where it's left as an exercise for the reader.

Any pointers? Or for that matter, proofs?

Comment: What's the link with hyperspaces, if I may ask?

Comment: My thesis is on the hyperspace of non trivial convergent sequences of a Hausdorff space, $\mathcal{S}_c (X)$. You can prove that whenever there is at least one non trivial convergent sequence on a Hausdorff space $X$, then $nw(X) \le nw(\mathcal{S}_c (X))$, and so, using this result (and the others I stated that I had already shown), you get that for locally compact, metrizable or LOTS, $nw(X) = nw(\mathcal{S}_c (X))$

Comment: Using $nw(\mathcal{S}_c(X)) \le w(X) = nw(X)$ or something similar, I presume.

Comment: Yes! I forgot to mention that the equality $w(X) = w(\mathcal{S}_c (X))$ holds whenever $\mathcal{S}_c (X) \neq \emptyset$, and therefore, $nw(\mathcal{S}_c (X)) \le w(\mathcal{S}_c (X)) = w(X) = nw(X)$

Comment: Did you understand the proof for LOTS? Or do I need to work out more details?

Comment: [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yasser_Ortiz-Castillo/publication/277972770_The_hyperspace_of_convergent_sequences/links/56a93dc908aeaeb4cef9394f/The-hyperspace-of-convergent-sequences.pdf) seems to be the seminal paper. Has it been cleared up whether $\mathcal{S}_c(\mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathcal{S}_c(\mathbb{P})$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: [this paper](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/ms.2018.68.issue-2/ms-2017-0114/ms-2017-0114.xml) seems right up your alley too.

Comment: The second paper you linked to is precisely the one I'm basing my thesis on. Since it's a bachelor level thesis, my task is to "translate" that paper so that someone who is doing their bachelor of mathematics can easily understand it. This means a lot of filling in gaps and solving "simple" statements like the one I asked here.
Regarding the proof for LOTS, I haven't had the time to look at it thoroughly, but it seems like a pretty straight forward proof using the concepts you've outlined. I'll get back to you if I get stuck though, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See lemma 3 on page 34 of [this paper by Hajnal](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andras_Hajnal2/publication/238844427_Some_remarks_on_a_property_of_topological_cardinal_functions/links/56137b4108aec7900afb7100.pdf) which shows that for $X$ a LOTS, $w(X) = d(X) + g(X)$, where $g(X)$ is the number of "gaps" of $X$, i.e.  open intervals $(u,v)$ with $u < v$, that are empty, so that two points are "direct neighbours". The proof of $w(X) \le g(X) + d(X)$ is not that hard: let $G$ be the set of all gap-endpoints (so for each $u < v$ with no $x$ with $u < x < v$, $u,v \in G$, and let $D$ be dense of minimal size, then the set of isolated points of $X$ plus all open intervals with endpoints in $G \cup D$ form a base for $X$, by some case distinguishing).

I think the proof of $w(X) \ge g(X) + d(X)$ can also be used to see that $nw(X) \ge g(X)$ (and $nw(X) \ge d(X)$ is clear), and then $w(X) \ge nw(X) \ge d(X) + g(X) = w(X)$ and equality ensues. This is clear: let $N$ be any network for $X$, then for each gap $(u,v)$, the set $(u,\rightarrow)$ is open and contains $v$ so $\exists N_v$ such that $v \in N_v \subseteq (u, \rightarrow)$ and it follows that $v = \min(N_v)$. So there are as least as many distinct members of $N$ as there are gaps.

For a connected LOTS, $w(X) = d(X)$ is easy to see, and $nw(X)$ sits between those two cardinals, so that's a boring special case.

Comment: What is d(X)???

Comment: @WilliamElliot $d(X)$ is  the density of $X$, the minimal cardinality of a dense subset of $X$ (as usual, rounded up to $\aleph_0$ for the finite case; likewise $g(X) = \aleph_0$ for the finite case as well, and for weight, the same holds).

Comment: Thank you! I have gone through your proof and it is quite clear and straightforward. Thank you as well for providing that paper by Hajnal. You're the man!

Comment: @AndoEscalando I'm glad I could help. Thx for the feedback, good luck with the thesis.